# How to choose value of k in RELIEFF Algorithm in MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, matlab, machine-learning

I'm using relieff algorithm to investigate the ranking of various inputs for solving a classification problem. I have five inputs and about 500 observations.
I'm using MATLAB to solve this.

I start off by setting the k nearest neighbors for the algorithm to 2 and vary it all the way till 450. The ranking computed for these
vary wildly initially and then stabilizes as the size of k nearest neighbors approaches 150. 
I'm attaching a graph of weight (higher weight - higher ranking) of each of the five attributes vs the number of k nearest neighbors below.

I'm wondering how to choose the value of k given for the ReliefF algorithm[image]?

Answer (score 4):

With the *K vs Weights* plot you've just answered your own question. That is indeed very smart.

The optimal K value for your dataset is where the elbow is (circa 350).
What does it mean? It basically means that taking into account another neighbour does not give a better modelling of the data.
You can object then that choosing 350 or 400 will lead to the same results since the weights are equal. Correct. However it is always recommended to choose for the smallest value because the model you're training will have a minor complexity (fewer number of neighbours to take into account) with respect to the same results (i.e. weights).

Such bruteforcing techniques are commonly used for many algorithms in machine learning:

- in K-NN to find the optimal number of neighbours
- in K-Means to find the optimal number of clusters
- in SVMs to find optimal tuning parameters

and so on and so forth...

I've been doing the very same experiment as you did, but with another dataset and I obtained the following plot:

[image]

and as you can see for this dataset the optimal K is circa 50.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. The size of my data set is 550, if k is 350, it would be comparable to the size.
http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/relieff.html
Matlab says : "If you set K to a value comparable with the number of observations (rows) in X, relieff can fail to find important attributes."

Comment: Well, for 550 I wouldn't call 350 "comparable". There is a difference of 200 over 550 patterns. Also in your case it doesn't fail to look for important attributes: the yellow is the most important and the others are less important. But if you look for K=250 and K=350 their behaviour is pretty much the same, they're just scaled down as K increases.

Comment: You can perform a nice analysis for K>=250. Yellow is always 1st place, blue is always 2nd and orange is always 3rd. At K=250 purple is above green but at circa K=270 green goes above purple and stays that way forever. However, you should take into account one important thing: the y-axis. Such weights differences are very small indeed, are they negligible for your case? If so, under what circumstances (i.e. threshold) such differences might be considered negligible? Well that is actually up to you, it depends on your actual problem.

Comment: Or, since you're working on a classification problem, you can perform two test cases: the first test case with weights at (let's say) K=250 and a second test case with weights at (let's say) K=350. Perform classification in both cases and see if the misclassification error (or accuracy) changes significantly.